# Updating a selected row in datatable in jsf

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am Creating a jsf application and I need to perform CRUD. So far I have managed to delete,create,and read but am unable to update the record.So my problem is, I want when the user click the update button a dialog box to pop with the details of the selected row and update the details. Here is My sample code.

```
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel value="Account Id"/>
        <h:inputText value="#{accCtr.acc.accountNum}" />
         <h:outputLabel value="Account Bal"/>
         <h:inputText  value="#{accCtr.acc.balance}"/>
        <h:outputLabel />
        <p:commandButton action="#{accCtr.create()}" value="Enter" update="dt"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
            <p:dataTable value="#{accCtr.list}" var="i" id="dt" style="width: 40%;" rowStyleClass="height" rowKey="#{accCtr.acc.accountNum}" >

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Account Num</f:facet>
                    #{i.accountNum}
                </p:column>
                   <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Account Balance</f:facet>
                    #{i.balance}
                </p:column>
                   <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>
                    <p:commandButton value="Remove" styleClass="height"
                                     action="#{accCtr.removeAccount(i)}"
                                   />
                     <p:commandButton value="Edit" styleClass="height"
                                     onclick="pop.show()"
                                     action="#{accCtr.edit(i)}"
                                      >

                     </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
   <p:dialog widgetVar="pop" header="Account Edit">
       <h:form>
           <p:panelGrid columns="2">

               <h:outputLabel value="Account Balance"/>
               <h:inputText value="#{accCtr.acc.balance}"/>
               <h:outputLabel/>
               <p:commandButton value="Update"/>
           </p:panelGrid>
       </h:form>
   </p:dialog>
```

can someone help me.
and my backing bean.

```
@ManagedBean(name="accCtr")
@SessionScoped
public class AccountController {



       List<AccountTable> list=new ArrayList<>();
        public AccountController() {
        }
       private Account_dao getDao()
       {
           return new Account_dao();
       }
        public List<AccountTable> getList() {

            return getDao().findAll();
        }

        public void setList(List<AccountTable> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }
        public void removeAccount(AccountTable acc) {
          getDao().remove(acc);
        }
        public AccountTable acc=new AccountTable();

        public AccountTable getAcc() {
            return acc;
        }

        public void setAcc(AccountTable acc) {
            this.acc = acc;
        }

        public void edit(AccountTable acc) {
            setAcc(acc);
        }
        public String create()
        {
            this.acc.setUserid(10);
            getDao().create(this.acc);
            return "index";
        }
```

Comment: Your create method looks so wrong, I mean its first line. And your edit method is incomplete. There is an attribute called selection and selectionMode in the datatable which you can use to bind with a selected object in your backing bean.. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Comment: @Sujan the create method is working correctly. I am Able to Insert a Record

Comment: You are hardcoding the user id, are you doing it for testing purposes ?

Comment: For User Id have hardcoded for purpose of testing but the rest is user input

Comment: Your question is not clear: the commandButton labelled `update` doesn't have any action attached. What are your expectations?

Comment: kolossus is right. There is no action attached to the button and the edit method is incomplete. You need to add a line that might look like `getDao().edit(this.acc);`..

Comment: @Sujan Sivagurunathan My problem is viewing selected row data on a dialog box that pop up

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
<p:commandButton value="Edit" styleClass="height"
                                 onclick="pop.show()"
                                 action="#{accCtr.edit(i)}"
                                  />
```

to

```
<p:commandButton value="Edit" styleClass="height"
                              oncomplete="pop.show()"
                              actionListener="#{accCtr.edit(i)}"
                              process="@this" update=":your_dialog_form_id"
                                  />
```

A few things: In general the `action` atributte is used for navigation (redirect to another page for instance). Also is better to use `oncomplete` beacuse it gets executed when your ajax request is completed, instead of onclick that fires the action (open the dialog in your case) in the moment when you press the button, skipping validation and such things.

If your problem was, refreshing the dialog content, with the update/process (ajax) mechanism, will be updated with your current selection if you do like the second snippet.